who is the subject in this sentence?

The subject in それが急に恐くなったって逃げ出したんじゃ締まらねえ is a little ambiguous to me. Is it the crew who is scared, or Robin? I would guess it's the crew, as in it would be 締まらない if they left, not dealing with her, despite taking her in. (sorry for the picture quality)

僕もそう思う、「全員…覚悟はあったはずだ…」から見ると

締まる means "to conclude/finish in a proper and satisfactory way", and 締まらない is a phrase used to point out something is finishing without a satisfactory ending. Possible translations would include "to have an unsatisfactory ending", "not being well put together", "wouldn't wrap things up properly", "leaving a bad taste in the mouth", etc. The subject of 締まらない is not a person but usually something like 会話, 物語, パーティー and 会議. In your context, the implicit subject is the hypothetical situation after 逃げ出した:

逃げ出したんじゃ締まらねえ。
If we/they run away, that's not a right way of ending this.

This is why the man said 落とし前(を)付ける時が来た (It's time to "settle" this, huh?) after it.
(If you're asking about the subject of 逃げる, it seems ambiguous from the given context. It's likely to be "we (the crew)", but it depends on the story up to this point.)

Thanks for the answer!!! I was mostly asking for the subject of 逃げ出す. I'll take your interpretation, as 恐い doesn't seem to really fit with Robin. It may have something to do with the crew being framed as criminals, therefore they "may" want to escape from the island, as they are being hunted. It's weird, because many translations say it's the Robin who runs, but other say it's the crew, so context here seems to be really limited
